# How can I draw a polyline with leaflet-draw to only get the shown dashed line and then disable the plugin?

Tags: typescript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am trying to use the Leaflet-draw plugin to draw a simple polyline. Right now I can enable the plugin where I need it when I start to draw the polyline and it works by adding the vertex to the start point and showing the dashed line on mouse moving. And I am using draw:drawvertex callback to deleteLastVertex on the second click.

But when I click on the second point, I have two possible click events: the first one is for the plugin and the second one is when I finish the polyline without using the plugin. I am trying to unite these two click events or better to disable the plugin before the first click event is trigged.
Have you any idea how can I fix it? Has anyone faced the same problem?

```
//First point drawn
L.Draw.Polyline(drawMap).enable();
L.Draw.Polyline(drawMap).addVertex(latlang);


drawMap.on('draw:drawvertex', function(e) {
 L.Draw.Polyline(drawMap).deleteLastVertex();
 L.Draw.Polyline(drawMap).disable();
}
```

Leaflet-draw intercept the click event that otherwise would draw the second point and a line between the first and second.

Comment: Having a code sample would be helpful. Also, it's not clear (at least to me) what you're trying to accomplish by disabling the plugin or uniting the click events. Can you clarify?

Comment: I added a little bit of code, I hope that can help!